# Stereo image acquisition using bumblebee2

Tags: c++, matlab, computer-vision, flycapture

I am using the Bumblebee2 camera and I am having trouble with acquiring stereo images from it. When I attempt to access the camera using MATLAB, the program crashes.

Does anyone know how I can acquire the stereo images using FlyCapture?

Comment: What program? How does it crash? What is the error message? You will need to give us a lot more information before we can get a sense of what the problem might be.

Comment: Why not using Triclops SDK for capturing? You should also be able do download several Code Examples from Point Grey.

Comment: Image Acquisition toolbox does support Bumblebee2 camera. What MATLAB version are you using? Can you come through MATLAB tech support and we should be able to definitely help you?

Answer (score 0):

Matlab cannot read the BumbleBee 2 output directly. To do that you'll have to record the stream and process it offline. I wrote a proprietary recorder based on the code samples in the SDK. You can split the left/right images and record each one in a separate video container (e.g. using OpenCV to write a compressed avi file). Later, you can load these images into memory, and use Triclops to compute disparity maps (or alternatively, use OpenCV to run other algorithms, like semi-global block matching).

Flycapture can capture image series or video clips, but you have less control over what you get. I suggest you use the code samples to write a simple recorder, and then load your output into Matlab in standard ways. Consult the Point Grey tech support.